# Updating Sql with PUT method not working in utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm writing an api that has POST, GET, DELETE and PUT methods
all request types are working properly except my PUT method that when english characters are sent to update, it's ok. But for persian characters it would not run.

Note:I'm sending data in header part of Ajax.
I've set encoding to utf-8 in header of html file and as told POST method with persian characters works fine.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $id = $headers['id'];
    $activityName = $headers['activityName'];
    $activityTime = $headers['activityTime'];
    $activityPrice = $headers['activityPrice'];
    $activityDoctor = $headers['activityDoctor'];
    mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");
    $updateAcSql = "Update activities SET activityname ='$activityName' , activitytime ='$activityTime' , activityprice ='$activityPrice' , doctorid ='$activityDoctor' WHERE id = $id";
    if (mysqli_query($db, $updateAcSql)) {
        $updateAcArray = array('mssg'=>'Updated');
        echo json_encode($updateAcArray);
    } else {
        $updateAcArray = array('mssg'=>'Not Updated');
        echo json_encode($updateAcArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: What part of this script is not working? Is it not hitting the method? Is the query not working? Do some troubleshooting to find out where it's breaking. if it's breaking on the query, instead of  just saying Not Updated, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Your data wouldn't normally be in the HTTP headers that you're using; you'd have to read from `stdin` to get the data with the PUT method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php